# i have "react-scripts": "^4.0.3", installed but still i'm not able to use Css Modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    **This is my Styles.css File**
   .headingStyle
    {font-size:4rem;
    color:blue;}
```

**Iam importing these styles here but nothing is being applied to the heading**

```
import React from "react"
import styles from "./Css/styles.css"

function App()
{
  return (
<div>
    <h1 class={styles.headingStyle}> CSS3 Testimonials Slider</ h1>

</div>
  )
}
export default App
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be styles.module.css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to create-react-app [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/) on CSS modules you should name your file **styles.module.css** and then import it like you already did

```
import styles from './styles.module.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

Import CSS file directly.
Use `className` instead of `class`

Try this

```
import React from "react"
import "./Css/styles.css"
function App()
{
  return (
<div>
    <h1 className="headingStyle"> CSS3 Testimonials Slider</h1>

</div>
  )
}

export default App
```